# How to fix 'ld: library not found for -lglib-2.0'

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer

I have to do a compiler with flex and bison for a school project.
They give to me example of new language but I can't compile them..
The code is working fine for other people so the problem come from my Mac. The problem appears when I try to compile with make command, he say "ld: library not found for -lglib-2.0".

I installed "Glib" already but this don't solve the problem.

```
make
[ 20%] Linking C executable facile
ld: library not found for -lglib-2.0
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [facile] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/facile.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I need to compile the code to work after on the project.

Thanks you

Comment: libglib-2.0.so path is not added in your make file. Find where that .so is present in your machine and add the path to your make file.

Comment: You can use probably can use pkg-config in order to obtain the flags for linking.  you can either run `pkg-config --libs glib-2.0` on the command line. In the makefile you can store the flags in a variable.

Comment: @Azux: what about this  `export LIBRARY_PATH="$LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib"`

Comment: @DINATAKLIT OMG, searched for hours, that was it. I wonder if this is a more common problem. I tried everything, reinstalling with brew, looking through file-system, changing build script. On Mac OS and this wasn't already set.

Comment: @DINATAKLIT Thank you so much, your suggestion resolved my problem! I just added that line to `~/.zshrc` and I was able to build my project.